# How to automate system configuration after reinstalling

Tags: software-recommendation

It is a bit boring to configure whole system every time i reinstall it.
I am looking for a neat tool that can help me automate all actions, like:

- software installing
- software confguring
- user creation
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some well known tools for this (in my order of preference):

- Puppet
- Chef
- cfengine

They do all require you to run a server to store the configs on though.